# Text input box/drop down menu in HTML

Tags: html, dreamweaver, textinput

I am trying create a prototype where one of the features is a dropdown menu similar to Facebook or Quora.

Essentially what I want is for a text input box to drop down with a set of "search results" I have predetermined.This is for a prototype/demonstration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete to the rescue!

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete